# Loading a JQuery array from a SharePoint list for autocomplete on a text field

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-autocomplete

I have an ordinary form with a text box, ID="I7", that my stakeholder wants to have a client side auto complete.  I have it working using server-side fetching of the data, but when I try to load an array with the values, the array seems to fill after the page load.

Working code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      supportScripts.actReportingSetup();

    headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose' };
        $("#I7").autocomplete ({
            source: function(request, response){
                var term = request.term;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://portal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('DocumentTypes')/items?$select=Title,TypeDescription&$top=500&$filter=startswith(Title,'" + term + "')",
                headers: headers,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map( data.d.results, function(item){
                        return{
                            label: item.Title + " - " + item.TypeDescription,
                            value: item.Title
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What do you guys suggest to get this running under from a client side array?

Comment: did you get a solution? I'm stuck on a similar issue

Comment: I did but I don't work there any more so I don't have the solution handy. :-)

Comment: hmm, no matter! thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a deferred promise for this. It would look something like this:

```
var defer = $.Deferred();

defer.done(function(){
    // code inside this block will run after your promise is resolved
});

function asyncEvent(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://yourUrlHere",
        headers: headers,
        success: function(data){ defer.resolve(data) },
        error: function(status){ defer.reject(status) }
    });
    return defer.promise();
});
```

You can find more information about jQuery deferred promises here: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: I ended up doing this:
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    headers: Headers,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item) {
            docTypeArray.push(
                            {label: item.Title + " - " + item.TypeDescription,
       value: item.Title});
        });
                    goAutoComplete(docTypeArray)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert('There has been an error:\n' + errorThrown);
    }
   })
  
  
            function goAutoComplete(myData){
    $("#I7").autocomplete ({
     source: myData
    });
            }

Answer (score 0):

Well, that comment was ugly.  Let's try this for formatting.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
$.ajax({
            url: URL,
            headers: Headers,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item) {
                    docTypeArray.push(
                        {label: item.Title + " - " + item.TypeDescription,
                        value: item.Title});
                });
                goAutoComplete(docTypeArray)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('There has been an error:\n' + errorThrown);
            }
        })


        function goAutoComplete(myData){
            $("#I7").autocomplete ({
                source: myData
            });
        }
```

Comment: Well that would work too! That's how I started out doing it too but after awhile I ended up with a lot of ajax calls, returning a promise lets me separate my "after" functions so I don't have to write out a different ajax function for each different success. Just a thought. However, if this works and you're happy with it, then I'm happy for you :)